Appwrite queries not filtering documents correctly
I am working on a project using Appwrite for my backend, and I'm encountering an issue with the queries in the listDocuments method. I have a collection of documents representing posts, each with a "status" field indicating whether the post is "active" or "inactive". However, when I use a query to filter for only active posts, the listDocuments method still returns both active and inactive posts.
async getPosts() {
    try {
        const query = [Query.equal("status", "active")];
        return await this.databases.listDocuments(
            conf.appwriteDatabaseId,
            conf.appwriteCollectionId,
            query
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Appwrite serive :: getPosts :: error", error);
        return false;
    }
}

I have also tried this method
    async getPosts() {
        try {
            return await this.databases.listDocuments(
                conf.appwriteDatabaseId,
                conf.appwriteCollectionId,

                [
                    Query.equal("status", "active")
                ]
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite serive :: getPosts :: error", error);
            return false
        }
    }

but both methods are not working.
Expected behavior:
I expect the listDocuments method to only return documents with "status" equal to "active", filtering out any documents with "status" equal to "inactive".
Actual behavior:
The listDocuments method is returning documents with both "active" and "inactive" statuses, instead of filtering out the inactive ones as expected.
Additional information:

I have verified that the status field in my documents is correctly set to "active" for the documents I want to retrieve.

I am using the latest version of the Appwrite SDK for JavaScript.

I have tried different variations of the query, including using Query.limit(1), but none of them seem to filter the documents correctly.


Can anyone help me understand why my queries are not filtering documents correctly in Appwrite? Is there a different approach I should take to filter documents based on their "status" field?
